# Flow Issue Populate Date/Time field to 12AM

Tags: date, time, salesforce, salesforce-flow

I want to update date/time field to 12 AM of a corresponding Date/Time field?
Like if startTime = 26/03/2022 3:40 AM or 26/03/2022 3:40 PM

the newField value = 26/03/2022 12:00 AM

I am stuck. Can any one help?

Comment: did you try : concat(formatDateTime(variables('DateVariable'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'T00:00:00Z')

Comment: this will be for GMT right? want it across all timezones